# Proof of excision

Tags: algebraic-topology

The following [link](http://books.google.de/books?id=bApVT-6A43QC&lpg=PP1&hl=de&pg=PA118#v=onepage&q&f=false) is the proof of excision from Rotman's Algebraic Topology. Please see the the third line of the page 118. I am wondering why the equation is held. Note that it is composition of q Subdivisions here.

Thanks very much.

Comment: There is no link.

Comment: The link is broken -- I don't know if draks tried to fix it or not, but it produces an empty Google book page for me.